# How to remove margin / padding from MaterialUI drawer?

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, redux, material-ui

I am working on a React app using MaterialUI to create an Appbar and Drawer.

There is an extra space between the edge of the window and the Drawer.

The extra space is also covering up an IconButton I use to toggle opening and expanding the drawer. It looks like this:

[image]

Here's how I'm rendering the Appbar and Drawer:

```js
render(){
    const { classes,drawerOpen,theme } = this.props;
    return(
      <React.Fragment>
        <AppBar
          position="absolute"
          className={classNames(classes.appBar,drawerOpen && classes.appBarShift)}
        >
        <Toolbar disableGutters={!this.state.open}>
          <IconButton
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="open drawer"
            onClick={this.handleDrawerOpen}
            className={classNames(classes.menuButton, drawerOpen && classes.hide)}
          >
            <ToggleLeft />
          </IconButton>
          <Typography variant="title" color="inherit" noWrap>
            MYAPP
          </Typography>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <Drawer
        variant="permanent"
        classes={{
          paper: classNames(classes.drawerPaper, !drawerOpen && classes.drawerPaperClose),
        }}
        open={this.state.open}
      >
        <div className={classes.toolbar}>
          <IconButton onClick={this.handleDrawerClose}>
            {theme.direction === 'rtl' ? <ToggleLeft />:<ToggleRight />}
          </IconButton>
        </div>
        <Divider />
          <List><SideAccountsList {...this.props}/></List>
      </Drawer>
      </React.Fragment>
      )
  }
```

Comment: Are you using the CssBaseline component (https://material-ui.com/style/css-baseline/)? This removes default margins and paddings.

Comment: No but thank you for the link! I'll look into it